# What are the best settings for a Windows 8.1 VM in VMWare Fusion 7.1?

Tags: windows-8, virtual-machine, macbook, vmware-fusion

I have a MacBook Pro, medio 2012 with 2.3GHz Intel Core i7 and 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3.

VMware Fusion 7.1 is installed on this MacBook to run a Windows 8.1 VM. This VM is my working machine. I do not work/use iOS. The company police is that we must use this setup, we can't use Bootcamp or something else. We must use VMWare Fusion and work with that.

At the moment I find my VM not performing too well. I'd like to get the maximum out of the Windows 8.1 VM. I don't have any other VM's by the way.

At the moment I have the following assigned to my VM:

- 3 processor cores
- 4096 MB memory

I would like to know what the best setup would be so my VM works the fastest. So, what would you  recommend me to do?

Comment: Why not use all cores? Unlike memory, processing time is a shared resource.

Comment: What does iOS have to do with a MacBook Pro?  You don't indicate what i7 you have so its difficult to determine how many cores the virtual machine can have access to.  But you only have two settings that could change.  Increasing the amount of memory the virtual machine has access to at the expense of the host and increasing the number of cores it has access to at the expensive of the host.  Only other thing would be to use a SSD.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, but what do you mean with 'You don't indicate what i7 you have'? What extra information do you need?

Comment: @DanielB I have 4 physical cores, but my processor support hyper threading, so it means I have 4 virtual extra cores. Should I then assign 4 or 8 cores to my VM?

Answer (score -1):

The Configuration is fine it would seem that your hard drive could be bottle necking. Though you could upgrade your hard drive to a SSD (Solid State Drive).